# How to do mathematical calculation by numbers within a text file in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a text file consists of numbers as:
1 2
3 4
I want to do mathematical calculations by these numbers and obtain an output as a text file as the following format:
2 6
3 12
There is no specific pattern with this calculations, I only need to perform basic multiplication. To illustrate, 1*2 = 2, 2*3 = 6, 3*1= 3, 4*3=12.
How can I do this?
Note: I am using "split" to store these characters. My code is provided below:

```
        var existingLines = File.ReadAllLines("../../okuma.txt");
        var newLines = new List<string>();
        var appendedLines = new List<string>();

        for (var i = 0; i < existingLines.Length; i++)
        {

            newLines.Add(existingLines[i]);
        }

        for (var i = 2; i < existingLines.Length; i++)
        {

            newLines.Add(existingLines[i]);
            var split = existingLines[i].Split('\t');
            var m = 2;
            var a = split[0];
            var b = split[1];
            appendedLines.Add(string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}", m, a, b, "I need to write the value of a*b here"));
        }
        newLines.AddRange(appendedLines);
        File.WriteAllLines("../../yazma.txt", newLines);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just do  `appendedLines.Add(string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}", m, a, b, a*b));`?

Comment: The Code you are missing is int.Parse() or better yet int.TryParse, this will convert the text to integers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [int.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse.aspx), e.g.

```
var a = int.Parse(split[0]);
```

Then you can multiply the numbers together.

Comment: That is not a valid call to TryParse. TryParse returns a bool and requires a string and out int as parameters. Just thought I'd throw that out there for those who don't click on the link

Comment: Ah, yes. Apologies, I've updated the answer to use int.Parse. :-$

Comment: Well now you've opened yourself up for exceptions! `int theNum = 0; bool success = int.TryParse(split[0], out theNum); if(success) { Console.WriteLine("Yay!" + theNum); } else { Console.WriteLine("Aww :("); }`

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 2; i < existingLines.Length; i++)
    {

        newLines.Add(existingLines[i]);
        var split = existingLines[i].Split('\t');
        var m = 2;
        var a = split[0];
        var b = split[1];
        var result = int.Parse(a)*int.Parse(b);
        appendedLines.Add(string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}", m, a, b, result));
    }
```